# Ошибка Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Обучаю `RandomRorest`-

Вот код:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                  test_size=0.8, 
                                  random_state=241)

RFC = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=37, random_state=241)
RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)

scor_test = []
for predict in RFC.predict_proba(X_test):
    x_scor = log_loss(y_test, predict)
    scor_test.apend(x_scor)
```

После выполнения последнего блока, ошибка:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-01347a72f1da> in <module>
      1 scor_test = []
      2 for predict in RFC.predict_proba(X_test):
----> 3     x_scor = log_loss(y_test, predict)
      4     scor_test.apend(x_scor)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in log_loss(y_true, y_pred, eps, normalize, sample_weight, labels)
   1762     """
   1763     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False)
-> 1764     check_consistent_length(y_pred, y_true, sample_weight)
   1765 
   1766     lb = LabelBinarizer()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    233     if len(uniques) > 1:
    234         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 235                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    236 
    237 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 3001]    
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples
```

Где я ошибся?

Дополнительная информация:

```
y_test.shape - (3001,)
RFC.predict_proba(X_test).shape - (3001, 2)
```

Может проблема в размерности матриц?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе полный `error traceback`?

Comment: @MaxU да, добавил в тело вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пропробуйте так:

```
In [6]: X_train.shape
Out[6]: (750, 1776)

In [7]: RFC = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=37, random_state=241)
   ...: RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)
   ...:
Out[7]:
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=37, n_jobs=None,
            oob_score=False, random_state=241, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

In [8]: predicted = RFC.predict(X_test)

In [9]: loss = log_loss(y_test, predicted)

In [10]: loss
Out[10]: 9.27641427545646
```

PS данный ответ показывает как избавиться от указанной в вопросе ошибки. Но из вопроса непонятно что автор хотел изначально сделать. Зачем считать "logistic loss" да еще и в цикле...

---

проверим точность модели на тестовой выборке:

```
In [11]: RFC.score(X_test, y_test)
Out[11]: 0.7314228590469843
```

Comment: К сожалению так тоже не работает. Воникает другая ошибка: Singleton array array(1, dtype=int64) cannot be considered a valid collection. Меня смущает то, что при обучении градиентного бустинга ошибки не возникает, а Случайный лес дает ошибку.

Comment: @ivan100096, можете выложить ваши данные `X` и `y` на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: да, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UFRo99gnRfktmu7JBBO5ob_chqbNbi35 - создал папку. Один файл - источник данных, другой - весь код, который использую

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: была ли возможность посмотреть эту задачу? Я уже второй день с ней вожусь - не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: @ivan100096, посмотрел и ответил 18 часов назад - смотрите измененный ответ... ;)

Comment: Блин, спасибо. Здесь же не надо было вызывать цыкл - ппц тупая ошибка)